# Binary Tree Pre order and Post order traversals identical?

Tags: binary-tree, traversal, postorder, preorder

Is there a binary tree in which this case is true?

I don't think so, unless the binary tree consists of only one root node.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: Suppose the root node has at least one child.

In pre-order traversal, the root node is processed first. The child comes after it. This is easily seen in the pseudocode:

```
preorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  print node.value
  preorder(node.left) 
  preorder(node.right)
```

In post-order traversal, the root node is the last to be processed and the child is first; see the code again:

```
postorder(node)
  if node == null then return
  postorder(node.left)
  postorder(node.right)
  print node.value
```

(pseudocode from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)).

In conclusion, if the binary tree has more than one node, the traversals are necessarily different.